# Adding rows/ columns to existing matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix:

```
a = [16 456 22 85 93;11 78 310 62 36;1 66 23 67 405];
```

If I wanted to add a row would it be `a = [a; randi(99, 1, 5)];`?
And what if I also want to add a column would it be `a = [a, randi(99, 4, 1)];`?

How would I add specifically between the first/second row or first/second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a = [16 456 22 85 93;11 78 310 62 36;1 66 23 67 405];` is a 3-by-5 matrix. So if you want to add a row you need to add a 5-digit row, i.e. `a = [a; randi(99, 1, 5)];` is correct. For a column it'd be `a = [a, randi(99, 3, 1)];`, where I replaced your `4` with a `3` to make it act on the initial matrix. Better though would be to implicitly use sizes, so that you don't have to manually increase the number of rows/columns each time:

```
a = [a; randi(99,1,size(a,2))]; %// adding a row
a = [a, randi(99,size(a,1),1)]; %// adding a column
```

If you want to insert your new row between the first and second rows:

```
a = [a(1,:);  randi(99,1,size(a,2)); a(2:end,:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
a = [16 456 22 85 93;11 78 310 62 36;1 66 23 67 405];
```

To enter before `ith` row:

```
a = [ a(1:i-1,:) ; randi(99,1,5) ; a(i:end,:) ];
```

To enter before `ith` column:

```
a = [ a(:,1:i-1) , randi(99,4,1) , a(:,i:end) ];
```